# Ubuntu 12.10 wireless shutdown issue

Tags: wireless, 12.10, shutdown

When I try to shutdown or restart my laptop it hangs at the point where it says "* will now halt" but never turns off. 
After some digging I have traced the root of the problem back to the wireless adapter. 
If I turn the wireless off before shutting down the system powers off correctly.

The wirless card is a broadcom BCM4313 and the system appears to be using the Broadcom STA wl driver. It currently has modules wl and bcma loaded but I have tried disabling both using "modprobe -r" and trying to use the other but the problem still occurs.

Can anybody advise me on what I can try next?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I resolved in this way:

1. `cd /etc/init.d`
2. `sudo gedit killwlan`
3. paste into:

   ```
      modprobe -r wl 

      modprobe -r bcma
   ```

   and save the file;
4. `cd /etc/rc0.d`
5. `ln -sT /etc/init.d/killwlan S16killwlan`
6. `cd /etc/rc6.d`
7. `ln -sT /etc/init.d/killwlan S16killwlan`
8. `cd /etc/init.d/`
9. `sudo chmod 755 killwlan`

In this way you stopped wifi kernel modules (that cause the halt of system) before shutdown procedure.