# Wireless driver (Relink RT3290) not working

Tags: wireless, drivers, 13.10, shutdown, restart

I'm having HP ProBook 450 and Ubuntu 13.10 with 3.11 kernel. Laptop was new, it came with SuSe Enterprise edition but as it was not possible to be translated to my local language I installed Ubuntu. According to Ununtu site - Relink RT3290 is certified to work with the system and this machine but for some reason - there is a lot of issue and I cannot fix it.

**Issue**: Wireless driver (Relink RT3290) not working correctly

**Symptoms:**

- system do not recognize the driver automatically until this is done ([How do I get a Ralink RT3290 wireless card working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253632/how-do-i-get-a-ralink-rt3290-wireless-card-working)). Extra guide as well
- when shutting down - the system restart itself
- one the system boot up - there is connection but when Internet site is open (or Skype turned on) - Linux shows kernel panic error

**What I have tried:**

- I had Ubuntu 12.04 - tried all suggestions from the forums - but it was not working, still the above symptoms.
- Upgraded to 12.10 with the below suggestions - still issues appear
- Upgraded to 13.10 with the below suggestions - still issues appear
- when I turn off wireless - no shutdown issue nor connection issue (via cable)
- i have added turning down wireless command to ~/.bash_logout script - not working (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77419/how-to-disable-wlan0-when-shutdown)
- from here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1134201&page=3 killwlan command - not working for some reason
- rfkill command not working for some reason
- shutdown from terminal when wireless is on is still restarting the system (http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=118094&sid=6872e90dc26f71758a19f626d8038568&start=20)
- this ([Ubuntu 12.10 wireless shutdown issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210306/ubuntu-12-10-wireless-shutdown-issue)) was not working as well, there is no killwlan file in /etc/init.d

Let me know if I need to provide you more info on this.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**1.download the file.**

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7kbO9nS2qKEMmQ5elZXVUhDRjA/edit?pli=1

**2.copy the folder named "rt3290sta-2.6.0.0" to /usr/src**

*i. Check the folder name again! The name should be [rt3290sta-2.6.0.0]

*ii. You cannot copy files to /usr/src? Open terminal and run

```
gksudo nautilus
```

,then GUI window will open. Find computer->usr->src, and paste the folder)

**3.In terminal, run**

```
sudo dkms install -m rt3290sta -v 2.6.0.0 –force
```

(It's for 14.04 LTS)